# Create new relations from an existing graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The aim of this query is to create new relations from an existing graph. I have `Category` nodes connected by `SUBCAT_OF` relationships. I want to extract the `SUBCAT_OF` paths from each `Category` (up to length 4) and use them to create a new paths consisting of `NEW_SUBCAT` relationships.

I am using the following query but I'm not sure that it works correctly:

```
MATCH (start:Category)
WHERE ()-[:SUBJECT]->(start)
MATCH path =((start)-[:SUBCAT_OF*1..4]-> (p1:Category))
UNWIND RELATIONSHIPS(path) AS rel
WITH STARTNODE(rel) AS s, ENDNODE(rel) AS e
MERGE (s)-[:NEW_SUBCAT]->(e)
```

Comment: Did you intend to require that the starting `Category` must have an incoming `SUBJECT` relationship?

Comment: Is this an attempt to clone a subgraph? If so APOC Procedures has some excellent procs that can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question did not state that the starting `Category` must have an incoming `SUBJECT` relationship. But since your query does filter for that, I will assume that is a requirement.

Your query (cleaned up slightly below) does do what you want.

```
MATCH (start:Category)
WHERE ()-[:SUBJECT]->(start)
MATCH path = (start)-[:SUBCAT_OF*..4]->(:Category)
UNWIND RELATIONSHIPS(path) AS rel
WITH STARTNODE(rel) AS s, ENDNODE(rel) AS e
MERGE (s)-[:NEW_SUBCAT]->(e)
```

Note: This query ensures that only a single `NEW_SUBCAT` relationship will exist between each distinct pair of `start` and `end` nodes (even if your DB had multiple `SUBCAT_OF` relationships between that same pair).

---

The following alternate query may be a bit faster, as it will first filter out duplicate relationships (produced by the [variable-length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) pattern):

```
MATCH (start:Category)
WHERE ()-[:SUBJECT]->(start)
MATCH path = (start)-[:SUBCAT_OF*..4]->(:Category)
UNWIND RELATIONSHIPS(path) AS rel
WITH DISTINCT rel
WITH STARTNODE(rel) AS s, ENDNODE(rel) AS e
MERGE (s)-[:NEW_SUBCAT]->(e)
```